# Correct DKIM, SPF, DMARC Record Setup for Emails Sent via AWS - SES

Tags: email, amazon-ses, email-validation, spf, dkim

I'm looking for help in fixing the email delivery issues; as almost 50-70% of our emails are getting flagged as spam by Gmail's filters. Here's how I've configured my current setup -

**Setup**

I use 'Mailcoach' as my newsletter/campaign software hosted on `crazyengineers.email`. Mailcoach sends email via AWS-SES. However, the mails are sent from `hello@crazyengineers.com` (not the TLD: .com vs. email). Both email address and domain are verified in SES.

For the past several years, we've kept our bounces/complaints to < 0.4%; which I believe is healthy.

I started sending out newsletter after a long gap of ~3 years and discovered that majority of mails were getting marked as spam by Gmail (and few other service providers).

**Troubleshooting Steps Performed**

So far, I've setup DKIM, DMRAC and SPF records as directed by several articles and blogs on the internet: -

```
DMARC:
_dmarc.crazyengineers.com TXT Routing: SIMPLE 
value: "v=DMARC1;p=reject;pct=25;rua=mailto:hello@crazyengineers.com;ruf=mailto:hello@crazyengineers.com"

SPF:
crazyengineers.com TXT Routing: Simple
value: "v=spf1 ip4:13.234.210.186 include:_spf.google.com include:amazonses.com ~all"

DKIM: 
exsdzadw3bnymparqj7feo5mpfqk5kdv._domainkey.crazyengineers.com  CNAME   Simple  -   
exsdzadw3bnymparqj7feo5mpfqk5kdv.dkim.amazonses.com

j3qbw4sa5w4g2m4nt2padhxm6y6sxbt7._domainkey.crazyengineers.com  CNAME   Simple  -   
j3qbw4sa5w4g2m4nt2padhxm6y6sxbt7.dkim.amazonses.com

oqahpkio2yww2enbd34rvq6xts52gtrc._domainkey.crazyengineers.com  CNAME   Simple  -   
oqahpkio2yww2enbd34rvq6xts52gtrc.dkim.amazonses.com
```

Even after adding these records - Google DMARC XML shows failures (and not a single PASS!).

Can someone help me achieve a proper, healthy records for my domain? I'm willing to move away from .email domain and host the mailing software on my subdomain say - `newsletter.crazyengineers.com`

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You keep misspelling DMARC as DMRAC (even in the DNS record)? This is not a programming question and belongs elsewhere on the site network.

Comment: I agree with @glts on this question being better suited on Server Fault forum for example. If you want help, please share the DMARC aggregate XML to see what is happening exactly with your delivery. Where did you get the CNAME records from? They should be coming from MailCoach for you to publish in your DNS. Not your own SES subscription.

Comment: Update - the records are all correct; and it looks like the issue resolved. I just need to send out another blast to ~4000 users to test. Looks like spam filters now acknowledge our records and also DMARC XML report shows ~90% pass. Thanks!